# Two variable inequality

Tags: inequality

I have the following set of conditions

$ x >= 100 $

$ x <= 150 $

$ y >= 100 $

$ y <= 150 $

$ x/y = 1.3 $

How should I go about finding a solution or a set of solutions for x,y. I havent done linear algebra in a long time so I would really appreicate any pointers.

In the above the constants (100, 150, 1.3) are different for different situations in my application so I cant assume those values will always be the same.

Comment: $y = x / 1.3$ is a line in the $(x, y)$ plane. The inequalities define a rectangle that the line needs to be clipped to. The end result will be the segment of the line that falls inside the rectangle, which you can determine by calculating the intersections with its sides. P.S. Neither `linear-algebra` nor `systems-of-equations` tags apply.

Comment: Thanks very much. That does help me visualize the solution. I have corrected the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the general inequality problem necessarily has a unique solution or even a solution.  Using the ranges you wrote, imagine that instead $x/y=2$.  This wouldn't have a solution.  If instead $x/y=0.7$ and your upper bound on y was extended to $y \le 200$, then there are infinitely many solutions (e.g., $y=150$ and $y=200$ both work).  You can think of this geometrically.  The equation $x/y=a$ can be rewritten as $y=\frac{1}{a}x=bx$.  If you plot this line, which passes through the origin, then you are essentially asking whether this line passes through a region of x-space and a region of y-space.  Either the line passes through the region, in which case every value on the line within the region is a valid solution, or it doesn't pass through, in which case there is no solution.